# C# Generic List<T> - How to Randomly Assign a "Rank" To Each Item?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, random, ranking

So i have the following generic list:

```
var topTenSomething = new List<Something>();
```

Here is **Something:**

```
public class Something
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

So i want to randomly assign the "Rank" property, but it needs to be ordered from 1-number of items in the collection.

So if the collection has 3 items, i want to randomly assign ranks from 1 to 3:

1. Some Name
2. Some Other Name
3. Something Else

Then next time, it could be:

1. Some Other Name
2. Some Name
3. Something Else

Know what i mean?

Not sure how to do it - any ideas?

This is for a simple R&D prototype - so don't worry about performance/why i am doing this. (the real one will have rank assigned by database)

Happy with either a LINQ/non-LINQ version - as long as it works.

Comment: Do the rankings have to be unique?

Comment: Do you want the collection to be sorted?

Comment: @SLaks - yes, at the end. I added that in after your stuff (see my comment to your answer below).

Comment: Could use this to fill a deck of cards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var rand = new Random();
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).OrderBy(i => rand.Next()).ToList();

for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    list[i].Rank = sequence[i];
```

If you want the list to be sorted by the random rank:

```
var rand = new Random();
list.Sort((a, b) => rand.Next(-1, 2));    //Exclusive upper bound
for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    list[i].Rank = i;
```

However, this is not a valid ordering (`a < b` does not imply `b > a`) and may cause unexpected results.

Comment: I think your OrderBy lamdba will break the IComparable contract, when the same `i` ends up with different values on repeated calls.

Comment: @Joel: I'm not sure; I've never tried it.  Note that this isn't directly IComparable.

Comment: @Joel, it works, I've done similar things myself for testing. Can't swear by the implementation, but presumably the lambda result of each item is cached so potentially expensive operations are not repeated.

Comment: Yeah this works. Couple of changes i made: 1) made `list[i].Rank = sequence[i] + 1;` (so rank starts at 1, not 0). also added a `OrderBy(x => x.Rank)` at the end to sort the list. But all in all, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @RPM: That should be `Sort`, not `OrderBy`.  (OrderBy isn't in-place)

Comment: And yes, as @Anthony Pegram said - this is for a prototype page. I dont care about performance/contracts here. The real rank will be assigned by data tier.

Comment: @SLaks - i mean i did it "dodgily", after your code: `myColl = myColl.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).ToList();`

Comment: @Joel. @Anthony: I checked the source.  `OrderBy` pre-creates an array of keys; the key selector will be called exactly once per element per `GetEnumerator` call.

Comment: @SLaks, that's what I figured. Didn't go as far as to check the source, but I did create a small program to follow it. Had it order on a property, and had a counter on the property's getter. Crude, but confirmed the property was only hit once.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
List<Something> somethings = new List<Something>();

/* TODO: populate list here... */

Random rand = new Random();
somethings.ForEach(s=>s.Rank = rand.Next(1, somethings.Count - 1));
```

Comment: I saw you wanted it sorted afterwards. Add this:   

somethings = somethings.OrderBy(s => s.Rank).ToList();